# Fetch large volume of data from DynomoDB?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, amazon-dynamodb, large-data

I am developing a spring boot REST API, which has to fetch large volume of data (100-200k records) from dynamoDB table based on search conditions and return the response to the API consumer without loading the entire object list in its memory. With SQL based database, I have used JDBCTemplate queryForStreams method for similar requirement. But for no-sql database like DynamoDB, I could not find similar methods to stream the data.

One sample scenario is to fetch all passengers who booked business class ticket on Christmas weekend from xyz airline dynamoDB database.

note: Edited for clarity.

Comment: For data that large, you're definitely going to want to stream the result to the client as it's read from DynamoDB. So I encourage you to use the pagination option. You didn't talk about what kind of scan / fetch you're doing, it would be helpful to know that.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Exactly you got my scenario. I need to stream data from DynamoDB like we use jdbcTemplate.queryForStream method for SQL database. I read from the DynamoDB articles that it has two types of stream options a) Kinesis and DynamoDB streaming, but both are event driven. But what I want is to fetch table based on my search condition.

Comment: Can you give some example of your search condition? Are you querying an index? Does the index contain all the columns you need, or are you just getting the ID from the index and then querying the table?

Comment: one example scenario is to fetch all passengers who booked business class ticket on Christmas weekend from an airline database. So it is based on some non-primary key search.

Comment: Is it done using a scan, or an indexed search?

Comment: it is done using scan. ex. dynamoDB.scan(scanRequest)

Answer (score 2):

Reading GB's of data per request from DynamoDB does not seem scalable. Does the end user require all that data, what is the purpose?

DynamoDB can only return 1MB per request so for a single end user API call you would have to make many paginated requests to DynamoDB.

If you are using `Scan` then your solution is not at all scalable and I would possibly suggest using a different database.

Comment: Thanks for your response. When using pagination, how to stream it in the response? So when data is fetched, it has to be immediately streamed, so that we can avoid out of memory issues.

Comment: This depends on which SDK you use. Some of the Java SDKs stream results but default (lazily loaded) others you will have to use Limit and iterate through the pages to mimic streaming.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good use case for REST in general. Have you considered storing the query result in an S3?

Your rest API will return a task id, that you can then use to check the progress of the query and eventually download the result.

This way you get infinite scalability and can run huge amounts of parallel dynamo scans or queries.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to do this is going to be using a parallel Scan operation. Assuming you have sufficient read capacity on the DynamoDB table, this is going to give you very high speed results.

See "parallel scan using Java" at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ScanJavaDocumentAPI.html for an example

Answer (score -1):

## DynamoDB

Think of DDB in the way that Amazon uses it, for e-commerce - small sub 100s list of paginated data, the items are usually small in size, but the items must be easy to update

In this case you would never need to store / fetch GBs of data from the tables

## Your needs as 'how might we...' question

How might we store GBs of data in AWS and retrieve that data quickly?

## AWS Best Practices

Before we dive in solving the 'hmw' question above we need to understand some core tenets of AWS

- operational excellence
- security
- reliability
- performance efficiency
- cost optimisation
- sustainability

AWS call these tenets or 'pillars' their Well-Architected Framework

You can read more about these here https://aws.amazon.com/architecture/well-architected/

Most of them are as described: monitoring, security, reliability, performance, cost efficient, computationally cheap (which means environmentally friendly)

## A sprawling buffet of solutions

### Storage

Your needs are the storage of GBs of data

It still depend on what you're trying to store here, but for most storage needs you'd use S3

To make sure we keep things 'compliant' with the Well-Architected framework we'd need to enable the use of encryption (in transite, at rest), block public bucket access etc.

To make everything cost efficient we will have to think about when we want to access this data. If accessed regularly then we'll have to use 'hot' storage, otherwise 'cold' storage S3 options are cheaper but you trade retrieval time.

#### Notable mentions

If you have specific data science needs you should checkout: Data Lakes (still uses S3 under the hood), Glue, Athena (a query layer on top of S3)

If you're storing text based data and require near instant seaching and retrieval using OpenSearch - this is very useful for chat related data

### Data storage

This depends of your app, but most people still keep a DynamoDB table that acts as a map for S3 queries.

DDB is query optimised and super performant when you fully understand you data queries or access pattern.

Design you table around your access patterns not around entities.

eg.

```
Option 1: One table

PK               SK
type#order       timestamp
type#transaction timestamp
....

Option 2: Multiple Entity based tables

Order table, 
PK         SK        Attr
id         timestamp productIDs

Transactions table
PK         SK        Attr
id         timestamp amount, orderId

Products table
PK         SK
id         category
```

The one-table design just simplifies the retrieval of data in a small number or requests, but you do need to play with your table design until it's just right.

My recommendation: be creative and mix and match the table styles to your needs. Entity-based tables are still useful in most apps.

Also expect to redo your tables once you find out new things.

It's crucial here that you use an infrastructure-as-code tool to make it easier to teardown and recreate tables - CDK is great for this.

Remember that you are billed per Read and Write units. This is where a well-designed table (to match your access patterns) will help you make concise queries at a low cost.

### Data retrieval

This is where you have some options, depending on your app

Again I would recommend the storage for big items in S3 not DynamoDB, so in this case it's relatively easy to download GBs of data from S3.

You can also store data in optimised formats using parquet.

Also if you choose to use DynamoDB as a hash map for the S3 bucket you can quickly find your files and locations and then place those in a queue, so that the retrieval happens in the background.

You can also copy files within the bucket to a job folder, zip the data and provide the user with the URL to that zip.

You can also use DataSync for copying across buckets.

### Final notes

It sounds to me like you are storing data in AWS and downloading for processing.

Most teams approach this by moving their processing and storage to AWS, running the whole process in the cloud.